# IOS:Connect peripheral device from table view when user select row

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-bluetooth

i am working on corebluetooth app. when i started discovering the devices in a tableview and when i am selecting the device to connect by using the  did connect delegate method in did select row at index path I'm getting and error in the console my code for discovering and connecting the device is specified below

for discovering the peripherals

```
 - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:  
    (CBPeripheral 
    *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
    {

    self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;
    _logData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did discover peripheral. peripheral: %@ rssi: %@,  
    `enter code here`UUID: %@   advertisementData: %@ ", peripheral, RSSI, peripheral.UUID,  
      advertisementData];
    NSLog(@"%@",_logData);


 [_periferalDevices addObject:peripheral.name];
 [_tableView reloadData];


 }
```

for connecting the peripherals

```
  - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral   

   *)peripheral
  {
   peripheral.delegate = self;

  [self.discoveredPeripheral discoverServices:nil];
   NSLog(@"Peripheral Connected");
   NSLog(@" started  time is %@",_timestring);
  // Stop scanning
 //[self.centralManager stopScan];
 NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");
  [self.data setLength:0];
[peripheral discoverServices:nil];


  [peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]];
  }
```

my confusion is in the below code what code we have to write for connecting the discovered device in table view after selecting a particular peripheral device in a selected row .

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   
    *)indexPath
    {
   if (_periferalDevices.count >0 )
  {
    CBPeripheral *peripheral =[_periferalDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;
    NSLog(@"selected peripheral - %@",peripheral);
   [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    [_periferalDevices removeObject:peripheral];
    NSLog(@"selected peripheral state - %d",peripheral.state);

     [tableView reloadData];

   NSString *strID = [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"%@",_discoveredPeripheral.identifier];
     strID = [strID substringFromIndex: [strID length] - 20];
     UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"conected" message:@""  
      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

 }

  }
  i am getting the errors as specified below
 2014-10-14 11:36:46.697 Bluetooth_iph[1705:368603] selected peripheral - MetaWatch 56
 2014-10-14 11:36:50.385 Bluetooth_iph[1705:368603] -[__NSCFString identifier]: unrecognized    
 selector sent to instance 0x14e67190
 2014-10-14 11:36:50.387 Bluetooth_iph[1705:368603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught   
 exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString identifier]: unrecognized    
 selector sent to instance 0x14e67190'

  *** First throw call stack:

  (0x28b47f87 0x36576c77 0x28b4d37d 0x28b4b259 0x28a7cd68 0x28818c7d 0xfb6db 0x2c0dcc57  
  0x2c18e2d7 0x2c040449 0x2bfbc30f 0x28b0e845 0x28b0bf29 0x28b0c32b 0x28a59db1 0x28a59bc3  
   0x2fdbc051 0x2c025a31 0xfc57d 0x36b12aaf)

    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

i have given he above code but connect peripheral delegate method is not working.please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line gives you the error. It says that you are accessing the identifier property on an NSString (which you can't do) so somewhere you have confused a peripheral and a string

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint or look at the stack trace to see which line has the problem.  I can't see an issue in the code you have shown here.

Comment: Have you changed `[_periferalDevices addObject:peripheral.name];` to `[_periferalDevices addObject:peripheral];` ?

Comment: i have changed that also but aim getting the error as follows..'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CBPeripheral isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175a3ad0'

Comment: Your array now contains `CBPeripherals`, not strings, so you need to use peripheral.identifier in that line

Comment: you need `identifier.UUIDString`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `peripheral.name` to the `periferalDefices` array you should add the `peripheral` object and retrieve the name in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Then your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will be as you have written it

Comment: i am able to get the name of the device but cannot connect to it getting some errors while i am giving the [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil]; in the code

Comment: i have updated the code with the errors  please find above and help thanks